# Filtering Based on Dates and ID's from Two Dataframes: Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two dataframes:
DF1:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|        ID|Dx_Min_Date|Dx_Max_Date|
|  30794324| 2014-04-21| 2015-07-01|
|  31234323| 2013-07-04| 2017-05-02|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

DF2:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|        ID|  Procedure|       Date|
|  30794324|         32| 2014-06-21|
|  30794324|         14| 2014-04-25|
|  30794324|         12| 2017-08-02|
|  54321367|         14| 2014-05-02|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to filter the Dataframe `DF2` based upon the ID's of `DF1` and being between the Min and Max dates as given by the columns `Dx_Min_Date` and `Dx_Max_Date`.  Resulting in:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|        ID|  Procedure|       Date|
|  30794324|         32| 2014-06-21|
|  30794324|         14| 2014-04-25|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is there a way to filter based on columns of one dataframe for another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non equi join:

```
df2.alias('tmp').join(
    df1, 
    (df2.ID == df1.ID) & 
    (df2.Date >= df1.Dx_Min_Date) & 
    (df2.Date <= df1.Dx_Max_Date)
).select('tmp.*').show()
+--------+---------+----------+
|      ID|Procedure|      Date|
+--------+---------+----------+
|30794324|       32|2014-06-21|
|30794324|       14|2014-04-25|
+--------+---------+----------+
```